# Determine whether $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{i^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges

Tags: complex-analysis

I am not sure if what I have done is correct:

I compare $\frac{i^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ with $\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ and have $  0\le \frac{i^n}{\sqrt{n}} \le \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ (However, I am not sure if this is correct).

By the Leibniz test, since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$ and since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \rightarrow 0$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$, I have that the original series converges. Would this be a correct way to show this?

Comment: Why not just break the series up into its real and imaginary parts?

Comment: Be careful. Inequalities make no sense with complex numbers.

Comment: @RonGordon - ahh right. Breaking it up into real and imaginary parts I get: $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{i^n}{\sqrt{n}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{i}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$$ Then pulling out the constants and using Leibniz on both, I get convergence. Would that be correct?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Both sums converge and their values expressed simply in terms of  $\zeta$ functions.

Answer (score 3):

The sequence of the real parts is
$$0,\frac{-1}{\sqrt 2},0,\frac 12,0,\frac{-1}{\sqrt 6},0,\ldots$$
and of the imaginary parts
$$1,0,\frac{-1}{\sqrt 3},0,\frac 1{\sqrt 5},0,\ldots$$

And the series corresponding to both sequences converge, by alternating series criterion (zeroes can clearly be ignored). Therefore, the series converges.